# css what am I missing to imitate this font

Tags: css, fonts

I tried to design my menu on photoshot and the result is

[image]

but when I tried to do the same think but when css, I got this result:
[image]

there is a little different in fonts and maybe fonts weight though I tried to do exactly the same thing,

could you tell me please on anyway that I can make the second image font like the first one?

http://jsfiddle.net/JmF36/

The text locates on the `#sidebar` id with this style:

```
#main-nav > li > a {
width: 100%;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
display: inline-block;
padding: 11px 18px 11px 18px;
outline: none;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

and I already set the font in the `#sidebar`

```
#sidebar {
font: 13px/1.7em "Open Sans", "trebuchet ms", arial, sans-serif;
background: #666666 url(../img/sidebar-bg.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is Web, not Photoshop. Your Fonts can't be perfect. At least not at this point in time.

Comment: @NoahWetjen yes I know that is why I am asking about a property to increase its value or a new property to add maybe it looks like the photoshop, I am sure there are many ways to workarround that

Comment: Are you looking at it on windows? It might look a little better on Mac just because the font is rendered differently. I am looking at it on Mac and it looks better than the images. But you won't get perfect font comparing to photoshop

Comment: @user2208349 Don't think there is something like that.

Comment: @Huangism yes, unfortunately, I am on windows. I don't want 100% exact font, maybe 90% is enough :)

Comment: @NoahWetjen lets wait for a better answer :)

Comment: @user2208349 you can try making the font an even number size, right now it's at 13, try 14px. I know there are display settings for font on windows but that's really up to the users to change. As far as I know there isn't much you can do about it

Comment: @user2208349 Well, there not being a property for this implies that there can't be a "good" answer.

Comment: @user2208349: have a look at my answer to get the exact match. Hope you will get the solution.

Comment: @SpiderCode I am checking

Comment: @NoahWetjen I told you there is a way :) check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself which is adding this :)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    src: local('Open Sans Extrabold'), local('OpenSans-Extrabold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/EInbV5DfGHOiMmvb1Xr-hnhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans Italic'), local('OpenSans-Italic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/xjAJXh38I15wypJXxuGMBobN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold Italic'), local('OpenSans-SemiboldItalic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxn5HxGBcBvicCpTp6spHfNo.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 800;
    src: local('Open Sans Extrabold Italic'), local('OpenSans-ExtraboldItalic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxkCDe67GEgBv_HnyvHTfdew.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- For parent menus like **Dashboard**, **Example Pages**, etc...

  Change `font-size` from `13px` to `1.1 em` and
  Change `font-weight` to `lighter`
- And for sub menu like **Regular Elements**, **Extended Elements**, etc...

  change `font-size` from `12 px` to `1 em`

Have a look at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JmF36/2/)

Comment: do you mean changing `font: 13px/1.7em "Open Sans", "trebuchet ms", arial, sans-serif;` in the `sidebar` to `font: 1.1em/1.7em "Open Sans", "trebuchet ms", arial, sans-serif;` **?** there is no problem all the links have the same font weight, it is good for me

Comment: in `#main-nav > li > a` change font-size to **1.1 em** and in `#main-nav .sub-nav > li > a` change font-size to **1 em**

Comment: no that didn't work, the font becomes bigger but still not wider like what I need, I believe it is something about making the font wider.

Comment: I would suggest one thing. You will not get the exact match. Have a look at my updated answer. You will get the exact match in firefox while in IE it will be little bit wider.

Comment: I found the solution myself, check my answer +1 to your efforts